# list view array filter

Tags: android, android-listview, arrays, android-filter

I have json array and i put all the items of the array inside the list. What i need is to do search for this list. I tried this function

```
 // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
    final EditText  editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    // Capture Text in EditText
    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter1.filter(text);

        }
    });
```

But when I try to type anything the list became blank

I have my filter inside the custom list adapter as below

```
// Filter Class
       public void filter(String charText) {
       charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
       movieItems.clear();
       if (charText.length() == 0) {
       movieItems.addAll(movieItems);
       } 
       else 
      {
       for (Movie wp : movieItems) 
       {
           if (wp.getNAME().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) 
           {
               movieItems.add(wp);
           }
       }
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `clear` before `addAll` so you are adding an empty list. Create a temporary "filteredList" and hold a reference to your "originalList"

```
// Filter Class
   public void filter(String charText) {
       charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
       List<Movie> filteredMovies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
       if (charText.length() == 0) {
           filteredMovies.addAll(originalMovieList);
       } 
       else 
       {
           for (Movie wp : movieItems) 
               if (wp.getNAME().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) 
                   filteredMovies.add(wp);
       }
       notifyDataSetChanged();       
   }
```

Remember that your custom adapter must handle th filteredList and not the original

Comment: Thank you so much but please can you explain how to handle the filtered list ?
I post my all adapter code
again thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what exactly your problem is without seeing your entire adapter code.  However it looks like you are manually implementing a method called `filter()` within your custom adapter? Your custom adapter (assuming it's extending `BaseAdapter`) should be implementing the `Filterable` interface which you would then access to perform a filtered search.

It can be difficult rolling your own solution. I suggest checking out the https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters repo. It contains a bunch of adapters which provide a really easy way to define your own filtering logic. There's also one specifically for using with `JSONArrays`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your filtered list is different from the main one and stores all the filtered results.

When you type in a search term the filtered list contains all the results. Set this list to adapter and then call notifydatasetchanged() with the new list.